# Git gui defauling to user directory instead of repo directory

Tags: git, git-gui

I'm fairly new to Git. I have a local repository setup under my user directory

C:/Users/username/git/repo-name

I'm using egit plugin from eclipse, and that seems to work fine.

However, when I launch "Git-gui", it defaulting to "C:/Users/username" and will show all the files under my username under "Unstaged Changes".

I checked config setting via "git config -l", "gui.recentrepo" is set to "C:/Users/username/repo-name"

Ultimately, I want to be able to check in/out from my web repo at github.

The issue is, Git-gui will scan through my entire user directory, which takes a long time to scan everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have ran `git init` into `C:/Users/username`. Your entire user directory is now considered a git repository. That's why `git gui` is showing all your files as 'Unstaged Changes'.

You have to remove the `C:/Users/username/.git` directory, or move it into `C:/Users/username/git/repo-name`.